# How to reduce ms access database file size(*.accdb) after deleting data in it (MS Office 2007)

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I want to reduce the ms access database file size after deleting data.

I have inserted some data in my test.accdb file, later i deleted the data from the file .

Before inserting data into it my file size was 10 kb.After inserting it became 2mb . later i

deleted the data but the size remains same.

I am using MS Office 2007.

Can anyone please say me how can i reduce the ms access database file size after deleting

data.

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have it in front of me, but from the main menu, `Manage`  then `Compact and Repair`

Office Help is your friend...

[Help prevent and correct database file problems by using Compact and Repair](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/help-prevent-and-correct-database-file-problems-by-using-compact-and-repair-HA010235583.aspx)